# Requirement "closed under finite intersection" in Van-Kampen-Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Given a topological space $X$, a point $x_0 \in X$ and an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ of path-connected subsets containing $x_0$ which is closed under finite intersections, we have by Van-Kampen
$$
\pi_1(X,x_0) = {\text{colim}}_{U \in \mathcal{U}} \bigl(\pi_1(U,x_0)\bigr).
$$

Is there a counter example in which all requirements are satisfied except "closed under finite intersection"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a concrete and (to my mind at least) particularly bad example: Take $X = B(0,2) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ the ball of radius 2 in the plane $U_1 = X - \{0\}$ and $U_2 = B(0,1)$. Then without accounting for the role of intersection, we would expect $\pi_1(B(0,2), (1/2,0)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, while the full space is obviously contractible.

Answer (score 2):

The 1984 paper available [here](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/Br-razak=vKT.pdf) gives the statement that if $\mathcal U =\{U_i,i \in I\} $ is a cover of $X$ by open sets and $A$ is a set which meets every path component of every 1-,2-,3-fold intersection of sets of $\mathcal U$ then the following diagram is a coequaliser of groupoids:

$$  \bigsqcup_{i,j}\pi_1(U_i\cap U_j,A) \rightrightarrows^a_b \bigsqcup_i \pi_1(U_i,A) \to ^c \pi_1(X,A) .  $$
Here $c$ is induced by the inclusions $U_i \to X$ and $a,b$ are induced respectively by the inclusions $U_i \cap U_j \to U_i,U_i \cap U_j \to U_j$. The condition on $3$-fold intersections is necessary as shown by an example in the cited paper, and another example in Hatcher's book on Algebraic Topology for the case of groups, i.e. when $A$ is a singleton.

Note that a major point of the use of groupoids is to have a Seifert-van Kampen type theorem which yields the fundamental group of the circle, and of other unions of non pathconnected spaces. See  this [mathoverflow discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one).

Answer (score 1):

This would imply that every space covered by two open path connected sets $U_1,U_2$ containing $x_0$ would have a free product $\pi_1 U_1 * \pi_1 U_2$ as fundamental Group.

Comment: Or take a disk around a point on a torus and the complement of that point. Then with a similar fashion as above, the fundamental Group of the torus would be proven free. You see that the closed under intersection property leads to quotiening out relations between different (the intersected) open sets.

Comment: Good explanation, would upvote if I could. :-)